# Common rows in multidimensional arrays in Python

Tags: matlab, pandas, numpy

I have two numpy arrays or two pandas dataframes with three columns and different number of rows.

I want to find where the rows of the first array exist in the second array. Something like matlab's ismember function

[~, idx] = ismember(a, b, 'rows')

Is there a similar function in python? I do not want to use a loop.

Comment: Inner merge with dataframes [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not want to merge the two dataframes. I want to find the indices where the two dataframes have equal rows.

Comment: you could still use merge and set the argument `indicator=True` and then sort by the `_merge` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx = npi.indices(a, b)
```

Comment: Is there a documentation for this package? Thank you.